# Java drawing logic

Tags: java, logic, draw

I've been making a logic simulator in Netbeans and I'm currently stumped on drawing the wires. When l place a component down such as a switch, it has an output point, which is clicked to create a wire start point. Then l click a gates input and that's the wire end point. A straight line is then drawn.

I need a way of clicking on the drawn wire to create a new point which can then alter the wires shape.

The logic simulator called Logic.ly has implemented for this and is shown below.

[image]

[Link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/975RT.png)

I don't need specific code, more of a general idea of how to implement this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the ideas you came up with yourself? There are a lot of ways to draw a line through a number of n points with regards to curvature and so on.

Comment: I would probably look into Splines if you want a similar solution to the one done by your reference image.

Comment: Yes. Splines work, I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: ArgoUML https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArgoUML have an drawing engine (Swing/Java2D) which you potentially can use. This is Open Source with Eclipse license.